# R: check that a sequence of numbers meets a certain tolerance level

Tags: r

```
values <- c(5, 3, 2, 2.9999, 2.9998, 2.9997, 2.99996, 2.9995, 2.9994, 2.9993, 
            9, 2, 1.9999, 2.9999, 2.9998, 2.9997, 2.99996, 2.9995, 2.9994, 2.9993)
```

I have a string of values, and I want to obtain the indices in which the difference between any two consecutive numbers is below some tolerance level.

```
tol = 0.001
> which(abs(diff(values)) < tol)
[1] 4  5  6  7  8  9 12 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

I want to make sure that the difference between any two numbers meets the tolerance level for at least 5 consecutive values, so the output should look something like this (no index 12 anymore because even though the difference between `2` and `1.9999` is below `tol`, the difference between `1.9999` and `2.9999` is not below `tol`, so the 5 consecutive number rule is not met)

```
4  5  6  7  8  9 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

How can I check the difference between any two numbers is less than the tolerance level for at least 5 consecutive values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `rle` to check for 5 consecutive values.

```
which(with(rle(abs(diff(values)) < tol), rep(values & lengths >= 5, lengths)))
#[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

Comment: `values2 <- c(2.68017937251098, 2.66215427522042, 2.63352814219648, 2.61458888391644, 
2.59555704055722, 2.58414675968589, 2.56624950368785, 2.55893596194507, 
2.5410599893748, 2.52999203256039, 2.51915161580392, 2.502599348604, 
2.49261782225617, 2.49261756139327, 2.49261732756173, 2.49261711787886, 
2.49261692978434, 2.49261676100152, 2.49261660950381, 2.49261647348539, 
2.49261635133574)` is a different string of values. However, running `which(with(rle(abs(diff(values2)) < tol), rep(values2 & lengths >= 5, lengths)))` gave me an error?

Comment: @YQW `rle` returns two components `values` and `lengths`, `values` in `rep` is from `rle` and not the vector `values`.  So you should use `which(with(rle(abs(diff(values2)) < tol), rep(values & lengths >= 5, lengths)))`,

Answer (score 0):

You could use stats::filter to check for 5 consecutive values that meet some condition.

```
which(filter(abs(diff(values)) < tol, filter=rep(1, 5), sides=1)==5) - 4
[1]  4  5 14 15
```

Which give the starting positions of the indices that have 5 consecutive values whose differences are within `tol`.